# Symfony join with many to many

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony

I would like to know how can I Make a join into another join.

My QueryBuilder

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder("t")
->leftjoin("t.playlist","p","WITH","p.genres=:genreP")
->setParameter(":genreP",$genre)
->addSelect("p")
->getQuery()
->getResult()
;
```

I had this error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 170 near 'genres=:genreP': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

What I am trying to do:

I have the **Trending** entity that has a relation OneToOne to the **Playlist** entity.The **playlist** entity has a relation ManyToMany to the **Genre** entity.

The trending entity:

```
class Trending
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
*@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Song", inversedBy="trending")
*/
private $song;

/**
*@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Album", inversedBy="trending")
*/
private $album;

/**
*@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Playlist", inversedBy="trending")
*/
private $playlist;
}
```

The playlist entity

```
class Playlist
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $titre;

/**
* @ORM\Column(name="public", type="boolean")
*/
private $public = true;

/**
*@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="playlists")
*@ORM\joinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $user;

/**
*@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Song", inversedBy="playlists")
*@ORM\joinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $songs;

/**
*@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Genre", inversedBy="playlists")
*/
private $genres;

/**
*@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"persist","remove","refresh"})
*/
private $image;

/**
*@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="playlistLikes")
*@ORM\JoinTable(name="playlist_likes")
*/
private $likes;

/**
*@ORM\Column(name="played", type="integer")
*/
private $played;

/**
*@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="playlistDislikes")
*@ORM\JoinTable(name="playlist_dislikes")
*/
private $dislikes;

/**
*@ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
*/
private $description;

/**
*@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Langue", inversedBy="playlist")
*/
private $languages;

/**
*@ORM\Column(name="lien", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $lien;

/**
*@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Trending", mappedBy="playlist", cascade=    {"persist","remove"})
*/
private $trending;
}
```

The

Trending table

```
id | playlist_id | song_id | album_id
54 | 9           | null    | null
```

The playlist table

```
id | title
9  | My best
```

The playlist_genre table

```
playlist_id | genre_id
9           | 1
9           | 4
```

The genre table

```
id | name
1  | Hip Hop
2  | Konpa
3  | Electronic
4  | Reggae
```

I would like to select any playlist where the genre_id is 4.

Thanks.

Comment: `->setParameter(":genreP",$genre)` should be `->setParameter("genreP",$genre)`. However I can't understand here the relationship between entities, could you post entity code? Moreover, why are you implementing the query from trending entity? Is that necessary?

Comment: I just edited my question. And it is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CONTAINS function?

```
->leftjoin("t.playlist","p","WITH","p.genres CONTAINS :genreP")
```

Edit: If contains doesn't work on the join you could always try it on a as where clause

Comment: I tried the CONTAINS function but I got this error like CONTAINS is not recognised.

Can you please show me how can I try with the where clause ?

I tried `->leftjoin("t.playlist","p")`
`->addSelect("p")`
`->where("p.genres = :g")`
`->setParameter(":g",$genre)` but I have the same error

Comment: I meant to try CONTAINS on the where clause. Or you could use MEMBER OF. It would be ->leftjoin("t.playlist","p","WITH"," :genreP MEMBER OF p.genres"); Again I've never used either MEMBER OF or CONTAINS on a join so you could switch from the leftjoin to a join and try them as where clauses

Comment: CONTAINS on the join or where gave me the same error. I have tried MEMBER OF but, It seems like it only verifies if the entities are the same family because, it returned all the playlists no matter if the id was what I needed. How can I put this forum as resolved?

Comment: You can mark your answer as answered by clicking the tick below the count  to the left of it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for This stupid Question.
I just resolve it by making two joins.

```
->leftjoin("t.playlist","p")
->leftjoin("p.genres","g")
->addSelect("p")
->where("g = :g")
->setParameter(":g",$genre)
```

This works. If someone have a better idea to optimise the request, I'm more than interrested!